# Watson Visual Recognition error code 400

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am trying to classify an image and following this [doc](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/tutorials.shtml). Here is my cURL command :

```
curl -X POST -F "images_file=~/fish.jpg" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key=12fdsxxxxxxxsadasdxxxxxxdsa45654&version=2016-05-20"
```

I am getting this response from the Watson:

```
{
  "error" : {
     "code": 400,
     "description": "No images were specified.",
     "error_id": "input_error"
  },
  "images_processed":0
}
```

My image is in `C:/User/Rajesh Kumar/` and cURL is executing in `Rajesh Kumar@RAJESH_KUMAR ~`. I know the problem is in the cURL command but don't know what. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even i tried curl -X POST -F "images_file=@~/fish.jpg" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key=12fdsxxxxxxxsadasdxxxxxxdsa45654&version=2016-05-20" but no help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are in the same directory as `fish.jpg`. Then run this command (replace API Key):

```
curl -X POST -F "images_file=@fish.jpg" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={api-key}&version=2016-05-20"
```

Don't use the tilda.

---

Just tried it out and it worked--here are the steps:

**Step 1:**

Download this file, and save it as `fish.jpg`:

[image: fish.jpg]

**Step 2:**

Make sure you're in the right directory:

[image: terminal]

**Step 3:**

Replace your API Key in this command and run it:

```
curl -X POST -F "images_file=@fish.jpg" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={api-key}&version=2016-05-20"
```

**Step 4:**

☺ ☺ ☺

[image: money]

Comment: Thanks it is working now. The problem was I was in wrong directory and using tilde(~) rather than @.